# pageLoad function in page and masterpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pageload

I'm trying to use function pageLoad() (asp.net related JS event)

I have one in the masterpage, and one in a different page. 
For some reason they don't want to be friends... only one is called.

When I cancel one, the other one is called so I don't see a problem there...

Any idea?

Master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="....." Inherits="......." %>



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <script>
        function pageLoad() {
            alert('masterpage load');
            CallStyledArrowSelect();

        }
    </script>


      //more irrelevant code

 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

And in the content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script>
   function pageLoad(){
     alert('hi i'm not working');
}
//more code...
```

Comment: Could you please show your code and explain what result you'e expecting?

Comment: ok i've added a partial code

Comment: I believe this article will help you: http://encosia.com/using-pageload-in-both-master-and-content-pages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

thanks to [andrey.shedko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924646/andrey-shedko) for the link,

Apparently it is not possible to have 2 pageLoad functions - one in the masterpage and one in the content page.
The solution suggested there is making another function on the content page and call it if it exist:

```
function pageLoad() {
    // Master pageLoad() code.

    // If function contentPageLoad exists, execute it.
    if(typeof contentPageLoad == 'function')
      contentPageLoad();
}
```